# How to Determine the Age of a Person in aTable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to determine the age of the people that are listed in my database. This is what I came up with, but I can't seem to limit the query to show people who are only 18 and under.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  patientdetails 
WHERE 
  ageInYears IN (
    SELECT 
      DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(p.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y'))/365 AS ageInYears 
    FROM 
      patientdetails p
  ) < 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patientdetails 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(p.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y'))/365 < 19
```

Comment: Zero results found. I know that this does return values though.  SELECT 
      DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(p.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y'))/365 AS ageInYears 
    FROM 
      patientdetails p

Comment: Can you post some example results from that query?

Comment: NVM, I see what I did wrong, your query is good. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM PatientDetails pd
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(p.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y'))/365 <19
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works:

```
SELECT *
FROM PatientDetails pd
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(pd.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y')) / 365 < 19
```

Dividing the days by 365 will fail to accommodate for leap years, meaning you will be off by 4 days guaranteed. You could divide by 365.25 and then subtract 0.75.  I *think* that accounts for everything, but I'm shooting from the hip a bit.  I'm not sure offhand if there would be integer errors with this calculation or not. I'm not sure how MySQL handles implicit typecasting.

I would be more inclined to do it this way. Logically, it's "all patients whose 19th birthday is in the future":

```
SELECT *
FROM PatientDetails pd
WHERE DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE(pd.DOB, '%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 19 YEAR ) > CURDATE()
```

However, this exact question is addressed and explained in the [MySQL documentation for date calculations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-calculations.html), but it seems kind of ass-backwards to me:

```
SELECT name, birth, CURDATE(),
(YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth))
- (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(birth,5))
AS age
FROM pet
```